# Разъясните своими словами что такое app.exec_() и что оно делает в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Я так понимаю это выход из окна, но если мы выйдем то оно закроется, а не будет ждать пока мы нажмем на кнопку выйти. Кстати, вообще это пишут как-то так `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, но я попробовал и 1, и 2 способ разницы я ни какой не увидел.

Так вот,

Разъясните своими словами что такое `app.exec_()` и что оно делает в PyQt5?

Comment: А чем вас не устроила выдержка из оф. документации? "Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q`[Core, Gui]`Application используется для доставки сообщений/событий объектам `Qt`, а также для взаимодействия с "окружающей средой", например оконным менеджером операционной системы.

Метод [exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) запускает цикл обработки событий, без этого цикла не будут работать виджеты.

Например описание из [переведенной документации](http://qtdocs.narod.ru/4.1.0/doc/html/qapplication.html#details):

> Класс QApplication управляет главным потоком и основными настройками приложения с GUI.
>
> Он содержит главный цикл обработки сообщений, где обрабатываются и
> пересылаются все сообщения посланные оконной системой и другими
> ресурсами. Также тут реализованы инициализация, завершение приложения
> и управление сессией. Также в данном классе реализованы возможности
> расширения системы и приложения.